# CSS flexbox: align action buttons vertically inside a card with varying amount of content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three cards where I need to align action buttons vertically, but the amount of content inside each card can vary and is not known beforehand. I can't just use `justify-content: space-between` because the content is placed inside another element that can have box shadow, background, etc. Cards are spaced using `padding`, let's say it's a requirement. Basically I need to expand the free space under each content block so that the buttons become aligned vertically. I've provided an example below: https://jsfiddle.net/jz3ogk06/27/
[image]

Comment: if you set `height: 100%` to the `.card-container` class it mostly does that, you'll have to play around with the placement of the content of that selector though (probably make it flex column with the content growing)

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't provided any HTML, I've added some to a snippet below. You'll notice that the parent elements will have a `display: flex`, attribute as well as the individual item blocks. Secondly, I added `flex: 1 1 0%;` to the text inside each block to allow it to take up the remaining room of its parent element.

```css
.container {
  width:1000px;
  background: #ebebeb;
  border:1px solid #d9d9d9;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:5px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  padding:5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: helvetica;
  line-height:20px;
  display:flex;
}

.item > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background:white;
}

.item p {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis mollis magna. Nam cursus tristique fermentum. Etiam volutpat nunc leo, ac tincidunt ipsum vehicula ut.           </p>
      <button> Button </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <p> Fusce congue vel nunc vitae eleifend. Duis eget elit a risus tempus vulputate. Suspendisse dignissim pretium lacus sit amet aliquam. Nunc tempor sodales ullamcorper. Aenean vel arcu in massa dignissim ullamcorper vitae eget nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
      <button> Button </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <p> Donec egestas tristique ante, a dictum massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Maecenas tempus dui tellus, eu ornare tellus euismod vel. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras nec pharetra mauris, sed condimentum nibh. Nullam scelerisque libero eu quam vulputate, tempor iaculis lorem pharetra. Maecenas in faucibus urna.</p>
      <button> Button </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```